# Meaning of S[3i]S[3i + 1]S[3i + 2]

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, suffix-array, array-algorithms

I have trouble understanding the following:
We have the String `ABRACADABRA`.  We divide this into groups as example:
`S` is divided into the group:

`S0 = <S[3i]S[3i + 1]S[3i + 2]  for i = 0,1,2...>`  where `<>` signifies an array and S[i] signifies the character in `S` in the position `i`.

I was expecting that `S0=<S[0]S[4]S[8]S[11]>` but according to the "solution" in the book I read it is not as `S0=[ABR][ACA][DAB][RA]` which is essentially `S[0]S[3]S[6]S[9]`.
So what am I reading wrong in the formula `S0 = <S[3i]S[3i + 1]S[3i + 2]  for i = 0,1,2...>`?

In case it matters it is from a chapter I read on Suffix Arrays. I only have trouble in the formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`S0=[ABR][ACA][DAB][RA]` is not `S[0]S[3]S[6]S[9]`. `S[0]S[3]S[6]S[9]` would be `AADR`.

This is what happens:

For `i=0`:
`<S[3i]S[3i+1]S[3i+2]> = <S[3*0]S[3*0+1]S[3*0+2]> = <S[0]S[1]S[2]> = <ABR>`

For `i=1`:
`<S[3i]S[3i+1]S[3i+2]> = <S[3*1]S[3*1+1]S[3*1+2]> = <S[3]S[4]S[5]> = <ACA>`

For `i=2`:
`<S[3i]S[3i+1]S[3i+2]> = <S[3*2]S[3*2+1]S[3*2+2]> = <S[6]S[7]S[8]> = <DAB>`

For `i=3`:
`<S[3i]S[3i+1]S[3i+2]> = <S[3*3]S[3*3+1]S[3*3+2]> = <S[9]S[10]S[11]> = <RA >`